# Generating database reports in Java

Tags: java, spring, reporting-services, spring-batch

I have a spring batch application which loads multiple files into several data tables.

I want to generate end of day report about the data loaded into these tables. Validation reports, comparing today's and yesterday's data, etc.

I there any good API available to generate such reports. By API, I mean which can help me in displaying results as charts, exporting report to pdfs or excels, etc.

I want to automate this thing. So I am planning to put it as last step in my jobs as a tasklet.

So tools will not be of much help here.

Is Jasper Report the answer to what I am looking here ???? How would it fit with spring batch ?

Comment: If you search for sources of statistical information, have a look at [`StepExecution`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.batch/spring-batch-core/2.1.8.RELEASE/org/springframework/batch/core/StepExecution.java#StepExecution). There are no reason why Jasper Report can't work with Spring Batch. What exactly problems you have?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this by creating a tasklet which is a JasperReport class.

Comment: share?  can you put that up on github or post the class here?